# Job is stuck in status 'Not started'

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I had a streaming job running on Google Cloud Dataflow with SDK 2.8.0. Last night it stopped emitting data to pub/sub.

I tried to run an update job. The new job got stuck in 'Not Started', and the previous job is in 'updating...' . This hasn't changed in hours.

Is everything normal in the platform? Any suggestions?

(The job Id is 2018-11-11_04_28_56-7460878465874177796 in case someone from Google is looking...)

Comment: To see if there are outages you can look at this dashboard https://status.cloud.google.com/ regarding your issue, to better investigate i recommend to open a issue in the public issue tracker or a support case if possible.